# Is it possible to use Azure CLI on DevOps (hosted/self-hosted) while connecting with managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I have a small test project with a crude start of a pipeline at https://github.com/veikkoeeva/dockerservice/blob/main/azure-pipelines.yml. It's currently just to check it's possible to connect to the Azure, so

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Az --version
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'TestManagedIdentityConnection'
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az --version

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'TestManagedIdentityConnection'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\devops.ps1'
```

But this fails on login step like so
[image: Azure DevOps failure]

The service connection scope is on subscription level. It appears the hosted image tries to connect to an Internal Azure token endpoint. Is there a way to use managed identity that can sign in the CLI using hosted images? What could it look like using self-hosted and managed identity?

This seem to work with "the usual" service principal. But it appears developers are often forbidden to create SPNs to company AD so creating a service connections fails. It appears often it's possible to create a service connection using managed identity, but here we are with this problem. :)

<edit: Reading from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest the options could be either `az login --identity` or a certificate. With `az login --identity` it appears there is still the same problem of calling the same endpoint as earlier and it errors with the same reason.

<edit 2: Duh! In the image it's called with `--identity` switch already!

Comment: According to this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1110711/are-there-any-microsoft-hosted-agents-with-msi-man.html) and [uservoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1059408/support-managed-identity-for-hosted-agent.html), managed identity will only work for VM based agent, not Hosted agent.

Comment: So it means not self-hosted nor Azure DevOps managed either. Maybe that leaves using username and password explicitly or using a certificate. Have to explore this a bit still.